# biblatex-chicago displays date twice in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago

I've been using biblatex for years but recently started to use the date field instead of year in my bib files. I have now created a bibliography with biblatex-chicago with the following preamble see below.

It looks all good but I get the date twice:

`Name, Firstname. YEAR. "Title." *Journal* Vol, no, (Month-Day-Year): page-page.`

I went through the documentation but cannot find out how to get ride of the second date field which is not just useless but not even required or necessary according to the Chicago style guide.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,draft=on,fontsize=12pt,headings=small]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}

\bibliography{publications.bib}
\begin{document}

\nocite{Author:year}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: For future question please keep in mind that we don't have your file `publications.bib`. So it would be great if you could post the code for the example entry `Author:year` in the question as well. That saves us some typing and ensures we are talking about the same thing.

Comment: Off-topic: The `.bib` file extension should not be included in `\bibliography`. It should be **`\bibliography{publications}`** and not *`\bibliography{publications.bib}`. Usually I recommend `\addbibresource` over `\bibliography` with `biblatex`. For `\addbibresource` the file name must be given with extension, so **`\addbibresource{publications.bib}`** would be correct as well. (TeX live usually accepts `\bibliography{publications.bib}` and finds the right file, but MikTeX on Windows will not find the right file and will attempt to open `publications.bib.bib` in that case.)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll keep that in mind for future posts as well as stop using the bib extension. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you play around with the `date` field you will find that the style only shows the date twice if the full date is more specific than just the year. Not knowing the exact details of the CMS I think this behaviour makes sense, but if it is indeed against the style requirements, please get in touch with the author of `biblatex-chicago` and report this as a bug (when I last emailed him I got a response incredibly quickly).

The date handling of `biblatex-chicago` is incredibly complex, so when you mess with it double- and triple-check that everything else is alright. It may also be desirable not to suppress the second, more precise date, for citations of newspapers (`@article` with `entrysubtype = {magazine},`) and a number of other entry types.

One easy solution without side effects would be to remove month and day information in the `.bib` file if it is not desired (or useful).

A way to get rid of the duplicated date automatically involves deleting fields more aggressively in the internal macro `clear+datefield`. That macro is executed after the date is printed for the first time. If we tell it to delete the date fields we won't print them the second time.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[authordate, backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}

\renewbibmacro*{clear+datefield}[1]{%
  \clearfield{#1year}%
  \clearfield{#1month}%
  \clearfield{#1season}%
  \clearfield{#1endyear}%
  \clearfield{#1endmonth}%
  \clearfield{#1endseason}%
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{appleby:y,
  author  = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  journal = {Journal of Important Things},
  volume  = {47},
  number  = {2},
  pages   = {134-178},
  date    = {1980},
}
@article{bppleby:ym,
  author  = {Humphrey Bppleby},
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  journal = {Journal of Important Things},
  volume  = {50},
  number  = {2},
  pages   = {134-178},
  date    = {1985-06},
}
@article{cppleby:ymd,
  author  = {Humphrey Cppleby},
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  journal = {Journal of Important Things},
  volume  = {53},
  number  = {2},
  pages   = {134-178},
  date    = {1990-07-01},
}
@book{dppleby:y,
  author    = {Humphrey Dppleby},
  title     = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  location  = {Place},
  publisher = {Pub \& Co.},
  date      = {1980},
}
@book{eppleby:ym,
  author    = {Humphrey Eppleby},
  title     = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  location  = {Place},
  publisher = {Pub \& Co.},
  date      = {1985-06},
}
@book{fppleby:ymd,
  author    = {Humphrey Fppleby},
  title     = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  location  = {Place},
  publisher = {Pub \& Co.},
  date      = {1990-07-01},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{appleby:y,bppleby:ym,cppleby:ymd,
  dppleby:y,eppleby:ym,fppleby:ymd}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Biblatex with single date]

Comment: Thank you moewe. That works well.